# cgi script runs as plain text instead of a webpage on mac

Tags: macos, apache, perl, cgi

I've followed this post to run the test.pl file:

```
 http://editrocket.com/articles/perl_apache_mac.html
```

I've also done some configuration in the httpd.conf file and here's a snapshot of what I did:

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Allow from all
</Directory>

.....
#
# "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
...
    #
# AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
# actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
# or added with the Action directive (see below)
#
# To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
# (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

Like the apache server is running as I run http://localhost, I get a "It works!" page. What else should I do to get the .cgi running?

Comment: bit more info? whats the URL you are using to execute the CGI script? when you say plain text do you mean your browser just shows the contents of the script rather than executing it?

Comment: What is your `ScriptAliased` directive set to?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I used http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.pl as I've put my pl file in the directory  /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables. And yes, it just shows the content of my script and not executing it though when I do perl test.pl, it does generate specified html tags in the terminal.

Comment: @RonBergin how should I check where my ScriptAliased directive has been set to?

Comment: @RonBergin if this is what you meant my ScriptAliased is set like this: ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So..I digged more into it and re-visited more stack overflow posts. It turns that I need to uncomment the line in the config file:

```
  LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
```

which isn't mentioned in the tutorial that I followed. Thanks for all the previous comments